# Recommended way for multiple domain names to Azure PostgreSQL flexible server

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have a data warehouse in PostgreSQL hosted on Azure, which needs to be accessed via different usernames for different marts (schemas) from PowerBI. PowerBI does not support having multiple users registered per server, which becomes a headache during development and difficult to manage also in production.

The only sensible solution seems to be to setup different domain names to the same service. To be able to do this with SSL encryption it is not enough to e.g. CNAME alias the domain names, as the certificates do then not match the names and the connection is not allowed.

Is there a recommended, reliable way to set up access via different domain names, with SSL certificates properly included? Maybe some layer 4 proxy, a hosted pgbouncer service, or the like?

I strongly prefer to not set up a virtual machine and host the proxy + certificates myself, but instead I'm hoping to find a managed service. Extra bonus points if it is within the Azure ecosystem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*PowerBI does not support having multiple users registered per server*"?...are you referring to PostgreSQL users ultimately?

Comment: It seems to be a well known limitation that each server (hostname) in PowerBI can only be associated with one (PostgreSQL) username + password. Since I have a user `mart_a` who gets to access only the `mart_a` schema, and a `mart_b` user who gets to access only the `mart_b` schema, I need to change the computer's global configuration of the single entry database host.

People are usually recommended to solve access rights via e.g. row level security or the like, but that does not match my use case.

Comment: If you use DirectQuery in PowerBI though, it'll connect to the database as whoever is running the report (you don't need to configure a dedicated PostgreSQL user). This is where row-level or regular database security can dictate which schemas your users have access to. I'm not sure how authentication works when it's a PostgreSQL database behind PowerBI but normally Active Directory (or Azure Active Directory in the cloud) is leveraged otherwise. Maybe these [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/concepts-azure-ad-authentication) would be of help.

Comment: There are also things like wildcard certificates and Subject Alternative Names that allow a single certificate to work with multiple domain names.